# How to remove multiple white spaces between words?

Tags: bash, output

```
grep include /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**output:**

```
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
    include             mime.types;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

**desired output:**

```
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
include mime.types;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Comment: Doesn't solve your actual problem but for anyone arriving at this question from a google search on the title: `tr -s ' '`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk '/include/ {$1 = $1; print}' < your-file
```

Would do that.

By assigning something to `$1`, that forces `awk` to rebuild the record by joining the fields (which by default are separated by whitespace (at least space and tab, possibly others depending on locale and awk implementation)) with `OFS` (space by default).

A `sed` equivalent:

```
sed -E '/include/!d; s/[[:space:]]+/ /g; s/^ //; s/ $//' < your-file
```

`[[:space:]]` includes `[[:blank:]]` which includes at least space and tab; `[[:space:]]` also includes vertical spacing characters¹, which is potentially useful here if the file has MSDOS CRLF line endings in that it would remove those spurious CRs at the end of lines.

---

<sup>¹ such as vertical tab, form feed which shouldn't occur in your input, line feed, the line delimiter which would not be in the record `awk` processes as `awk` processes the *contents* of each *line* in turn</sup>

Answer (score 3):

That should be simply doable with sed:

```
% sed -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/  */ /g' file.txt
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
include mime.types;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

`s/pattern/replacement/` does a find-and-replace, `^` means the start of the line,  `*` any number of spaces and   `*` is just a single space followed by any number of spaces. The `g` at the end is for "global", i.e. to replace all matches.

Replace the space with `[[:space:]]` if you also have tabs there, i.e.:

```
% sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//g' -e 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/ /g' file.txt
```

Comment: yep, I've tried the sed before but the last two strings stay with muiltiple white spaces.
I found the best way trough `awk`, I'll post it as answer

Comment: mm, which last two strings? the last two lines you showed? You might have a tab there, using `s/[[:space:]]*/ /g` should help with that.

Comment: `[[:space:]]*` also matches the empty string, so `s/[[:space:]]*/ /g` would insert a space between all characters.

Comment: yep, the comment above was wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to use Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.30;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>){
    $_ =~ s/[[:blank:]]/ /g; #replace any number of subsequent space with single space except newline
    $_ =~ s/\s//; #remove single space at the beginning of each line
    print("$_");
}
__DATA__
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
    include             mime.types;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

If you want to try one-liner version from command line:

`perl -nE '{$_ =~ s/[[:blank:]]+/ /g; $_ =~s/^\s//; print $_}' file.txt`

Comment: Since `\s` also matches newline, that adds a space at the end of each line. Note that `$_` is the default variable `s/.../.../` acts upon. Better as `perl -lne 'if (/include/){s/\s+/ /g; s/^ //; s/ $//; print}'` or `perl -lase 'print @F if /include/' -- -,=' '`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you. I have overlooked. I will fix it.

Comment: I updated with POSIX character class, hope this is acceptable answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
grep include /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: that would only print the second field, dropping the `include` word from each line, so it doesn't exactly give what you showed in the Q. You could use `awk -F ' ' '{$1=$1; print}'` though, it'd rebuild the fields with only that one space in between